# Unable to read SMS from the Nokia phone using GSMComm

Tags: sms, nokia, gsm, sms-gateway

I'm implementing a project for [reading and parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256665/how-to-send-receive-sms-messages-from-c-application-using-nokia-mobile-phone) SMS from Nokia Xpress Music 5800 using [GSMComm library](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm#gsmcomm)

I tried using GSMComm Demo: I'm able to get phone information, different status such as battery/storage and send SMS. But I'm not able to read SMS from the phone, it's giving following error:

```
Error: The phone reports an unspecified error.
```

This typically happens when a command is not supported by the device,a command is not valid for the current state or if a parameter is incorrect.
    (`GsmComm.GsmCommunication.CommException`)

Since I use DLL's I don't see which commands are being sent to the phone. Also I doubt that all other commands work, except the ones reading the SMS.

Questions:

1. Main Question: what are possible causes of the problem?
2. I know it's difficult to answer above question. So is there any logs/dumps/events being logged in some place? I'm totally new in this area (hardware interfacing) and need starting point for troubleshooting
3. Stretch: If I implement using above technology (USB to COMM emulator, GSMComm), what's the portability of my application? Definitely GSMComm dll needs to be shipped. But does this mean that the target PC needs to have Ovi Suite (containing USB to COMM emulator) installed? What about portablity on the phone: will it work only WITH Nokia Xpress Music 5800, or will it work with other Nokia phone as well. Or with  any other phone?"

> More info: OS on my phone is in
>   Cyriliic alphabet, if that matters.

Updated the question: since some of the questions were answered after a week of investigation.

Update 2: I've followed instructions in this [link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/AT_Commands). My phone is responding to some of the commands, but giving "ERROR" for others. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm

I'm sure you've gone over this page, but at the bottom it tells you how to check the logs for GSMComm. Unfortunately, I have never worked directly with GSMComm and couldn't tell you what the root cause of the problem is, but try checking the logs. If you haven't read through the FAQ, I would do so, it may shed some light on the questions you are asking.

As far as portability, if you require a third-party emulator for you to run it, that would have to be a pre-requisite for others to use your application. Any GSMComm DLLs that contain code you use would also be required for distribution or else your program won't work.

Comment: I've already gone through the step you pointed out. But no help. Also  "Update 2" on the question points out that problem is not necessarily caused by the GSMComm library.

Comment: Commands querying general phone status (like battery/memory) works, but AT commands related to SMS (like Read) are not

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using 3rd generation phone so that you can't access the AT commands that are used to read SMS. I advice you to use an old(er) Nokia phone, here is a list of some:

- Nokia 5210
- Nokia 610
- Nokia 6200
- Nokia 6210
- Nokia 6103
- Nokia 6131
- Nokia 6230